Outbound call failed to route the service based on custom header
I have implemented a feature in the External Processor gRPC service where a custom header is dynamically added to outbound calls. The intent is to route these outbound calls based on the value of this custom header. However, despite this configuration, the virtual service does not appear to be routing the requests as expected.

Call should route based on custom header. I have added virtual service, Envoy filter, code to add the custom header in service.
Virtual Service and Envoy filter
**apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: service-B
spec:
  hosts:
  - "serviceB"
  http:         
  - match:
    - headers:
        X-CUSTOM-HEADER:
            exact: "2024.07.P"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: serviceB.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8082** 



**External-Processor service
try {
          response = ProcessingResponse.newBuilder()
              .setRequestHeaders(
                  HeadersResponse.newBuilder().setResponse(
                      CommonResponse.newBuilder().setHeaderMutation(
                          HeaderMutation.newBuilder().addSetHeaders(
                                  HeaderValueOption.newBuilder().setHeader(
                                      HeaderValue.newBuilder().setKey(X-CUSTOM_HEADER).setRawValue("2024.07.P").build()).build())
                            .build()).build()).build()).build();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
         
          e.printStackTrace();
          throw e;
        }
        responseObserver.onNext(response);
      }**
    
**Envoy Filter
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: envoy-internal-process-filter
  namespace: default
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    # select by label in the same namespace
    labels:
      app: svca
  
  configPatches:
    # The Envoy config you want to modify
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
              # subFilter:
                # name: "envoy.filters.http.router"  
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        # Adds the Envoy External Processing Filter in HTTP filter chain.
        
        value:
          name: envoy.filters.http.extproc
          typed_config:
            "@type":      type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_proc.v3.ExternalProcessor
            failure_mode_allow: false
            async_mode: false
           
            grpc_service:
              envoy_grpc:
                cluster_name: outbound|9001||envoy-external-service.default.svc.cluster.local
                authority: envoy-external-service.default.svc.cluster.local
              timeout: 10s  
            message_timeout: 10s
            allow_mode_override: true
            
            processing_mode:
              request_header_mode: "SEND"
              response_header_mode: "SKIP"
              request_body_mode: "BUFFERED"
              response_body_mode: "NONE"
              request_trailer_mode: "SKIP"
              response_trailer_mode: "SEND"**  


Call should route based on custom header added by external processor
grpc service called by envoy filter.
If I route the request using prefix of api path and print the headers in destined or upstream service, I am ble to see the newly
added custom header in target service. Somewhere virtual service
unable to read the newly added custom header.

